# SharePoint Custom List Form doesn't validate required fields

Tags: validation, sharepoint-2007, requiredfieldvalidator, newforms

**My Story:**

I had to customize the page `NewForm.aspx`, so I hidden the default `ListFormWebPart` and added a Custom List Form [`DataFormWebPart`] using SharePoint Designer.

**My problem:**

If required fields are empty, SharePoint now triggers a beautiful ***Error*** page instead of putting the usual validation message below each empty fields.

Do you have any idea how I can **reactivate** the **empty required field validation**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the client side validation routine is not getting called.

The `ListFormWebPart` does this in `OnLoad();`

```
this.Page.Form.Attributes["onsubmit"] = "if (typeof(_spFormOnSubmitWrapper) == \"function\") return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();";
```

Which looks to inject the client side validation call.

The `DataFormWebPart` web part only seems to inject it when async is turned on.

You might have to add it in manually.

Comment: ...(Hi) Is there a way to add the async on with SharePoint Designer?